# vsftpd conditional pasv_address (internal ip vs. external ip)

Tags: ip, ftp, vsftpd

I have a vsftpd server setup that I'd like to be able to access with passive transfer from an external IP (use of my domain name) and also from my local network (192.168.1.x). Currently I have /etc/vsftpd.conf setup to be accessible externally:

`pasv_enable=Yes
 pasv_max_port=<max>
 pasv_min_port=<min>
 pasv_addr_resolve=YES
 pasv_address=<domain name>`

this works fine however when I want to connect locally it attempts to use the resolved IP for the passive address (external vs. local).

Is there a way to conditionally cause vsftpd to use different pasv_address depending on where the connection originated?

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the `pasv_address` line so that the server takes the address from the connected socket. Check the manual: http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html